# Winpython (portable) and Qt Designer converting .ui to .py

Tags: qt, python-3.x, qt-designer

I am using Winpython portable with Python 3 and Qt Designer 5.5.  The tutorials I have found say to convert the .ui file to .py with pyuic.  I cannot find the file pyuic in my directories.  I am using windows 7 and the portable version of WinPython.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed PyQt and Qt already? http://pythoncentral.io/install-pyside-pyqt-on-windows-mac-linux/

If so, open up cmd and go to the same directory as your .ui file and use: 
    pyuic5 input.ui -o output.py

Hope this helps.